# Как правильно построить иерархию классов простой игры?

Tags: c#, архитектура

[image: задание]

Я имею такую проблему, что не знаю как сделать верно, моя архитектура на корню не верна, я бы хотел знать как сделать более правильно, что бы при расширении не было проблем.

```
namespace Game_taskApp
{
    class Player : IWalk
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public char simbol;

        public int Walk()
        {
           
        }
    }
    interface IWalk
    {
        abstract int Walk();
    }
    class Field
    {
        private int _weight;
        private int _height;
        private char _border;

        public Field(int weight, int height,char border)
        {
            if (weight < 15 || weight > 50)  { weight = 15; }
            if (height < 15 || height > 50) { height = 15; }
            _weight = weight;
           _height = height;
           _border = border;
        }
        public int GetWeightField()
        {
            return _weight;           
        }
        public int GetHeightField()
        {
            return _height;
        }
        public int GetBorder()
        {
            return _border;
        }
    }

    class Bonus
    {
        private int _bonus;
        public Bonus(int bonus)
        {
            if(bonus < 0 ||bonus > 15)
            {
                bonus = 10;
            }
            _bonus = bonus;
        }

        public int GetBonus()
        {
            return _bonus;
        }
    }
    class Enemy : IWalk
    {
        private int _quantity;
        public Enemy(int quantity)
        {
            if (quantity < 0 || quantity > 10)
            {
                quantity = 10;
            }
            _quantity = quantity;
        }
        public int GetEnemiesCount()
        {
            return _quantity;
        }
        public void Walk()
        {

        }

        int IWalk.Walk()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class Wood
    {
        private int _wood;
        public Wood(int wood)
        {
            if (wood > 10 || wood < 0)
            {
                wood = 10;
            }
            _wood = wood;
        }
        public int GetWood()
        {
            return _wood;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: соберите все существительные из вашего задания - это и будут ваши классы.

Comment: А что конкретно в вашем коде, как вам кажется, неверно? Здесь важно чтобы вы сами поняли, если считаете, что неверно или наоборот все верно. Здесь вас могут максимум подтолкнуть. P.S. Вы же знаете, что weight - это вес, а ширина - это width?

Comment: Солидарен с @tym32167. Также добавлю, что стоит обратить внимание на глаголы (что каждая сущность игры умеет делать), чтобы сформировать методы этих сущностей

Comment: Я использовал обычно с иерархией своих классов наследование, здесь же мои классы не общаются между собой, например поведение движения игрока и врагов должно зависеть от моего поля например, я хочу сделать модульно в плане отделить классы от самой реализации игры, поэтому для меня это важно, Максим спасибо за уточнение) Я к сожалению не знал.

Comment: За замечание по именованию, спасибо. Я переделаю.

Comment: `я хочу сделать модульно в плане отделить классы от самой реализации игры` это надо в вопросе писать

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что за конструктор у `Wood`? Это же препятствие, которое требуется обойти. Зачем значение какое-то? Хотя судя по классу `Enemy` это классы не конкретно одного объекта, а целой группы. Ну то есть функция `GetEnemiesCount` говорит о том, что `Enemy` отвечает за всех врагов на карте, а не за конкретного. И хотел спросить, а почему вы не используете свойства?

Comment: Ну, я думал что я создам лист с деревьями и рандомно при каждой новой игре буду раскидывать их по площади, поэтому, как и врагов я определенное количество хотел сделать, написать алгоритм что бы он охотился я конечно не знаю, но сделать так что бы он передвигался по кругу или линии думаю мог бы. А про свойства Ну я думал по этому поводу, я хотел изначально писать правильно и решил скрыть реализацию после инициализации обьекта, это правильно как я понимаю, более модульно, мб я ошибаюсь. Но это почти тоже же самое. Я инициализирую и отдаю данные поля обратно.

Comment: Я не спец, но думаю что можно сделать класс типа `Game` и в нем уже хранить кол-во врагов и препятствий на карте, объект типа `Field` и `Player`.

Comment: В качестве идей для вдохновения почитайте эту статью: https://habr.com/en/post/322258/